# How to deploy Java or Dotnet webservices in Linux-based shared hosting server?

Tags: linux, web-services, server, host

Please see this link [from a hosting provider](https://www.nettigritty.com/). I have read "Linux-based shared hosting server".

I am front end developer. I don't have much knowledge regarding server side. I have applications based on Dotnet and Java. I want to deploy Webservices which is written in both (Java or Dotnet programming language) in Linux-based shared hosting server.

For a simple project, I don't want to go for cloud based server.

What are the steps required for this? How to achieve this without using server?

Comment: Usually the deployment method is dependent on Web Server in use. So it would be better if you provided more information about Server you are trying to deploy to. As far as Java is concerned - you usually create a single .war or .ear file (where whole web or enterprise application is packaged) and then just copy it to specific directory (autodeploy) - after that web application is auto-deployed.

Comment: @Plirkee - Thanks for your kind reply. The thing is, we have one IP address. Consider there is one IP address 192.1.168.19 which is shared and Static IP. Since, If I ping this IP address in command prompt, Its showing me like another domain name eg : intention.com which is not belongs to our company ABC. It means that shared IP address. How to deploy webservices in linux based hosting server?

Comment: As interesting as this topic is, it is rather too broad for Stack Overflow. I will try to close it.